# How to connect to Mysqldb hosted on AWS using AWS Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda

Hi im trying to connect to mySQL server hosted on aws using an AWS lambda function.I'm very new to this so it would be of great help if someone could provide me any sample code.
Objective is to devlop an alexa skill which retrieves certain data from the db and provides this as output

Comment: What issue are you having? So far you've posted a statement, not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Please read lambda documentation on creating lambda deployment package which will answer your question. Ensure the packaged environment is same as Lambda Environment (Amazon Linux)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html